# SyntaxError: invalid syntax Python

Tags: python, bash, shell

I have a python script. This is only my conversion to my shell script, Sorry Im just newbie for this language. the error is:

```
  File "chkrpm.py", line 19
    if(rc != 0):
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I don't know whats wrong. This is my shell script

```
retval=0
for i in $(cat /var/tools/tools/newrpms.txt)
do
        ls /var/patchbundle/rpms/ | grep $i
        if [ $? != 0 ]
        then
                echo "$i NOT FOUND!"
                retval=255
        fi
done
exit $retval
```

And this is my python conversion. Just focus on the error side.

```
import package, sys, os, subprocess

path = '/var/tools/tools/newrpms.txt'

newrpms = open(path, "w")
fds = newrpms.readline()
newrpms.close


def checkrc(rc):
                if(rc != 0):
                        sys.exit(rc)
cmd = package.Errata()
retval=0


for i in newrpms:
        rc = cmd.execute("ls /var/patchbundle/rpms/ | grep %newrpms ")
                if(rc != 0):
                    cmd.logprint ("%s not found !" % i)
                    retval = 255

checkrc(rc)
```

Whats wrong in my code. That's it fit like my bash script?

When I tried to follow all the suggestion below error found:

```
 File "chkrpm.py", line 19
    echo("%s not found !" % i)
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: note:  `newrpms.close` doesn't do anything.  If you want to close the file, you need to call the function:  `newrpms.close()` :-).

Comment: You are opening the file in write mode and trying to read from it. change the open as `newrpms = open(path, "r")`

Comment: Try using `print` instead  of `echo`

Comment: There are so many issues with your code that you might as well be asking us to just write it for you. I assume the shell code runs fine. You should just use it instead of trying to rewrite it in Python, especially if you're going to try to treat Python like it's shell.

Answer (score 0):

Your Error message say `invalid syntax' because your indentation is wrong

your for loop looks like:

```
for i in newrpms:
        rc = cmd.execute("ls /var/patchbundle/rpms/ | grep %newrpms ")
                if(rc != 0):
                    cmd.logprint ("%s not found !" % i)
                    retval = 255
```

when it should look like:

```
for i in newrpms:
    rc = cmd.execute("ls /var/patchbundle/rpms/ | grep %newrpms ")
    if(rc != 0):
        cmd.logprint ("%s not found !" % i)
        etval = 255
```